# Найти первое число в массиве между нулями

Tags: java

Дана функция, в ней два параметра: массив целых чисел и размер массива. Найти в массиве первое число, которое окружено нулями. Если такое число не найдено, верните -1, или верните индекс такого элемента.

```
public static int method(int[] array, int arraySize) {}
```

Comment: Вы не знакомы с циклами и сравнениями?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int method(int[] array, int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 2; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0 && array[i + 2] == 0) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```